# Apache / .htaccess : website optimizations

Tags: php, .htaccess

I make my website from scratch with PHP. In order to optimize performance, loading time and security I use a lot of online tools : google page speed insight, gtmetrix, dareboost.com, webpagetest etc...

Dareboost.com advises me to set headers in my .htaccess file like :

- Content-Security-Policy
- X-FRAME-OPTIONS
- X-XSS-Protection
- X-Content-Type-Options

I did :

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' www.googletagmanager.com ;"
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
```

It seems to be a little bit inefficient : when I look into my waterfall timeline I see that all my assets (CSS, JS, fonts, IMG) use those directives but not my first GET request (on www.mydomain.com).

Why ? Due to that, Dareboost doesn't understand that I set properly my headers.

Comment: If you want a optimized webserver, don't use .htaccess files, put the config in the .conf site files.

Comment: @Anuga I have a lot of other websites on this virtualhost and don't want to impact them :)

Comment: Perhaps you have a redirect between www and non-www ?

Comment: @Paolito75 I don't understand how you can impact them? Having .htaccess files, is bad practice, better to have the config in the .conf files, you don't need to restart the whole server or webserver even, just do a reload instead of restart when doing changes.